# Is there a Java data structure that is effectively an ArrayList with double indicies and built-in interpolation?

Tags: java, data-structures, interpolation

I am looking for a pre-built Java data structure with the following characteristics:

1. It should look something like an ArrayList but should allow indexing via double-precision rather than integers.  Note that this means that it's likely that you'll see indicies that don't line up with the original data points (i.e., asking for the value that corresponds to key "1.5").  **EDIT**: For clarity, based on the comments, I'm not looking to *change* the ArrayList implementation.  I'm looking for a similar interface and developer experience.
2. As a consequence, the value returned will likely be interpolated.  For example, if the key is 1.5, the value returned could be the average of the value at key 1.0 and the value at key 2.0.
3. The keys will be sorted but the values are not ensured to be monotonically increasing.  In fact, there's no assurance that the first derivative of the values will be continuous (making it a poor fit for certain types of splines).
4. Freely available code only, please.

For clarity, I know how to write such a thing.  In fact, we already have an implementation of this and some related data structures in legacy code that I want to replace due to some performance and coding issues.

What I'm trying to avoid is spending a lot of time rolling my own solution when there might already be such a thing in the [JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html), [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) or another standard library.  Frankly, that's exactly the approach that got this legacy code into the situation that it's in right now....

Is there such a thing out there in a freely available library?

Comment: I'm guessing no one else has written such a thing.  I know for a fact it's not in the standard library, as it's a highly specialized, limited use collection.

Comment: @OMG: it wouldn't even be a `Collection` according to the interface specification, because it would be pretty hard to specify the number of elements ('though it would be possible when considering the finite precision of `double`).

Comment: I was looking for a linear interpolation java class, oddly enough apache commons math has many interpolation methods (spline, neville,...) , but not linear.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't exist because it doesn't make sense.  You're asking for something "like an ArrayList" except it's nothing like an array list.  Can you please clarify which is more important to you, the front end (ie interface), or the back end (the interpolator functionality).  The back end is orders of magnitude harder to implement, wrapping an interpolator in a List-like interface is trivial.

Comment: @Graphics, the interface to the developer using the code should appear to be like an ArrayList in the sense of get(t) where t can be a double, thus possibly requiring interpolation (see points 1 and 2).  With respect to "trivial", yes, you can create an O(N) implementation which, for large N and frequent accesses, will be a performance limitation.  This is one of the problems with the legacy code that I'm currently trying to replace which does all of the above, just not well.

Answer (score 4):

Allowing `double` values as indices is a **pretty large change** from what `ArrayList` does.

The reason for this is that an array or list with `double` as indices would almost by definition be a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array), which means it has no value (or depending on your definition: a fixed, known value) for almost all possible indices and only a finite number of indices have an explicit value set.

There is no prebuilt class in Java SE that supports all that.

<strike>Personally I'd implement such a data structure as a [skip-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) (or similar fast-searching data structure) of `(index, value)` tuples with appropriate interpolation.</strike>

**Edit:** Actually there's a pretty good match for the back-end storage (i.e. everything except for the interpolation): Simply use a [`NavigableMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) such as a [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to store the mapping from index to value.

With that you can easily use [`ceilingEntry()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingEntry(K)) and (if necessary) [`higherEntry()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#higherEntry(K)) to get the closest value(s) to the index you need and then interpolate from those.

Comment: For clarity, I'm not looking for a change to the ArrayList.  I'm looking for something like the interface, not a change to the original implementation.

Comment: @Bob: that's what I thought, I just wanted to point out that "something like ArrayList" implies a level of similarity that probably can't be reached.

Comment: really?  That's the code that I'm looking at right now but I'm trying to replace with a better implementation.  The front-end interface isn't hard to achieve.  It's the under-the-covers implementation that requires actual work.

Answer (score 3):

If your current implementation has complexity O(log N) for interpolating a value, the implementation I just made up may be for you:

```
package so2675929;

import java.util.Arrays;

public abstract class AbstractInterpolator {
  private double[] keys;
  private double[] values;
  private int size;

  public AbstractInterpolator(int initialCapacity) {
    keys = new double[initialCapacity];
    values = new double[initialCapacity];
  }

  public final void put(double key, double value) {
    int index = indexOf(key);
    if (index >= 0) {
      values[index] = value;
    } else {
      if (size == keys.length) {
        keys = Arrays.copyOf(keys, size + 32);
        values = Arrays.copyOf(values, size + 32);
      }
      int insertionPoint = insertionPointFromIndex(index);
      System.arraycopy(keys, insertionPoint, keys, insertionPoint + 1, size - insertionPoint);
      System.arraycopy(values, insertionPoint, values, insertionPoint + 1, size - insertionPoint);
      keys[insertionPoint] = key;
      values[insertionPoint] = value;
      size++;
    }
  }

  public final boolean containsKey(double key) {
    int index = indexOf(key);
    return index >= 0;
  }

  protected final int indexOf(double key) {
    return Arrays.binarySearch(keys, 0, size, key);
  }

  public final int size() {
    return size;
  }

  protected void ensureValidIndex(int index) {
    if (!(0 <= index && index < size))
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index=" + index + ", size=" + size);
  }

  protected final double getKeyAt(int index) {
    ensureValidIndex(index);
    return keys[index];
  }

  protected final double getValueAt(int index) {
    ensureValidIndex(index);
    return values[index];
  }

  public abstract double get(double key);

  protected static int insertionPointFromIndex(int index) {
    return -(1 + index);
  }
}
```

The concrete interpolators will only have to implement the `get(double)` function.

For example:

```
package so2675929;

public class LinearInterpolator extends AbstractInterpolator {

  public LinearInterpolator(int initialCapacity) {
    super(initialCapacity);
  }

  @Override
  public double get(double key) {
    final double minKey = getKeyAt(0);
    final double maxKey = getKeyAt(size() - 1);
    if (!(minKey <= key && key <= maxKey))
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("key=" + key + ", min=" + minKey + ", max=" + maxKey);

    int index = indexOf(key);
    if (index >= 0)
      return getValueAt(index);

    index = insertionPointFromIndex(index);
    double lowerKey = getKeyAt(index - 1);
    double lowerValue = getValueAt(index - 1);
    double higherKey = getKeyAt(index);
    double higherValue = getValueAt(index);

    double rate = (higherValue - lowerValue) / (higherKey - lowerKey);
    return lowerValue + (key - lowerKey) * rate;
  }

}
```

And, finally, a unit test:

```
package so2675929;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class LinearInterpolatorTest {

  @Test
  public void simple() {
    LinearInterpolator interp = new LinearInterpolator(2);
    interp.put(0.0, 0.0);
    interp.put(1.0, 1.0);

    assertEquals(0.0, interp.getValueAt(0), 0.0);
    assertEquals(1.0, interp.getValueAt(1), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.0, interp.get(0.0), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.1, interp.get(0.1), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.5, interp.get(0.5), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.9, interp.get(0.9), 0.0);
    assertEquals(1.0, interp.get(1.0), 0.0);

    interp.put(0.5, 0.0);

    assertEquals(0.0, interp.getValueAt(0), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.0, interp.getValueAt(1), 0.0);
    assertEquals(1.0, interp.getValueAt(2), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.0, interp.get(0.0), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.0, interp.get(0.1), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.0, interp.get(0.5), 0.0);
    assertEquals(0.75, interp.get(0.875), 0.0);
    assertEquals(1.0, interp.get(1.0), 0.0);
  }

  @Test
  public void largeKeys() {
    LinearInterpolator interp = new LinearInterpolator(10);
    interp.put(100.0, 30.0);
    interp.put(200.0, 40.0);

    assertEquals(30.0, interp.get(100.0), 0.0);
    assertEquals(35.0, interp.get(150.0), 0.0);
    assertEquals(40.0, interp.get(200.0), 0.0);

    try {
      interp.get(99.0);
      fail();
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      assertEquals("key=99.0, min=100.0, max=200.0", e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
      interp.get(201.0);
      fail();
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      assertEquals("key=201.0, min=100.0, max=200.0", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private static final int N = 10 * 1000 * 1000;

  private double measure(int size) {
    LinearInterpolator interp = new LinearInterpolator(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      interp.put(i, i);
    double max = interp.size() - 1;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      sum += interp.get(max * i / N);
    return sum;
  }

  @Test
  public void speed10() {
    assertTrue(measure(10) > 0.0);
  }

  @Test
  public void speed10000() {
    assertTrue(measure(10000) > 0.0);
  }

  @Test
  public void speed1000000() {
    assertTrue(measure(1000000) > 0.0);
  }
}
```

So the functionality seems to work. I only measured speed in some simple cases, and these suggest that scaling will be better than linear.

**Update (2010-10-17T23:45+0200):** I made some stupid mistakes in checking the `key` argument in the `LinearInterpolator`, and my unit tests didn't catch them. Now I extended the tests and fixed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Apache commons-math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/), if you implement the [UnivariateRealInterpolator](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/interpolation/UnivariateRealInterpolator.html) and the return value of its interpolate method which is typed [UnivariateRealFunction](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/UnivariateRealFunction.html) you'll be most of the way there.

The interpolator interface takes two arrays, x[] and y[].  The returned function has a method, value() that takes an x' and returns the interpolated y'.

Where it fails to provide an ArrayList-like experience is in the ability to add more values to the range and domain as if the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is growing.

Additionally, they look to be in need of some additional interpolation functions.  There are only 4 implementations in the library for the stable release.  As a commenter pointed out, it seems to be missing 'linear' or something even simpler like nearest neighbor.  Maybe that's not really interpolation...

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge change from ArrayList.

Same as Joachim's response above, but I'd probably implement this as a binary tree, and when I didn't find something I was looking for, average the value of the next smallest and largest values, which should be quick to traverse to.

Answer (score 0):

Your description that it should be "like an ArrayList" is misleading, since what you've described is a one dimensional interpolator and has essentially nothing in common with an ArrayList.  This is why you're getting suggestions for other data structures which IMO are sending you down the wrong path.

I don't know of any available in Java (and couldn't easily find one one google), but I think you should have a look at [GSL - GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/index.html) which includes a [spline interpolator](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Interpolation.html).  It may be a bit heavy for what you're looking for since it's a two dimensional interpolator, but it seems like you should be looking for something like this rather than something like an ArrayList.

If you'd like it to "look like an ArrayList" you can always wrap it in a Java class which has access methods similar to the List interface.  You won't be able to actually implement the interface though, since the methods are declared to take integer indices.